# What is the meaning of using have/had been?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the below sentences?

a) Robin said it appeared that the intention of Lubitz *had been* "to destroy the aircraft".

b) The prosecutor said that this action could only *have been* "voluntary".

and if I say

a) Robin said it appeared that the intention of Lubitz *was* "to destroy the aircraft".

b) The prosecutor said that this action could only *be* "voluntary".

Comment: What do you think the differences are based on what you know? If we know what is confusing you, it will help us to help you better.

Comment: Hi Catija I have two sentences which conveys same meaning hence i m confused. Also what is the special meaning impact of Had/have been in my example.

Comment: Just an added note, this sort of quote usage requires that they be **inside** punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

The first two imply that the action is finished while the bottom two imply that it is ongoing... case A is a bit more complicated because it's past tense and there's not as much difference between them so I'll use a similar example to case B that's a bit clearer:

> The woman's hair could only have been "brown".

The hair was brown at some point in the past.  Maybe she dyed it or it went grey but there's no *requirement* that it's still brown.

> The woman's hair could only be "brown".

The hair is still brown. For some reason, the woman can not change her hair color.

I'll admit this is a bit absurd but it's the simplest way of showing the difference.